# running simple mathjs example: “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string“

Tags: javascript, node.js, mathjs

I’m very new to `node.js`, and am just trying to learn the basics. I’m using the [play.js](https://playdotjs.com/) IDE on my iPad and want to try some simple math-related javascript. I have successfully used [jStat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jStat) functions within the IDE, so I know that I *can* get it to work.

I’d like to use [mathjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjs), so I’ve resolved the dependency in my test project, and my `package.json` now looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jstat": "^1.9.3",
    "mathjs": "^7.2.0"
  }
}
```

The files all appear to be installed under the `node_modules` directory.

In my `index.js`, I just have the following example code straight from the `mathjs` help:

```
const { sqrt } = require('mathjs')
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
    at Array.join (<anonymous>)
    at Array.toString (<anonymous>)
    at Array.join (<anonymous>)
    at Array.toString (<anonymous>)
    at Array.join (<anonymous>)
    at Array.toString (<anonymous>)
    at mixkey (/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8FF30C6F-8C40-4A4C-BA59-869F18430F8D/Documents/apps/TEST3FB8CAB9-FC43-4D65-9554-11E37599A1BB/src/node_modules/seed-random/index.js:135:25)
    at module.exports (/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8FF30C6F-8C40-4A4C-BA59-869F18430F8D/Documents/apps/TEST3FB8CAB9-FC43-4D65-9554-11E37599A1BB/src/node_modules/seed-random/index.js:35:19)
    at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8FF30C6F-8C40-4A4C-BA59-869F18430F8D/Documents/apps/TEST3FB8CAB9-FC43-4D65-9554-11E37599A1BB/src/node_modules/mathjs/lib/function/probability/util/seededRNG.js:18:65
```

If it helps, that line in `lib/function/probability/util/seededRNG.js` looks like this:

```
var singletonRandom = /* #__PURE__ */(0, _seedRandom["default"])();
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Is there something I need to read to understand why this won’t run, or is this an issue with `mathjs`?

Comment: This error log goes into `seed-random` package. Can you try to use it separately from math.js?

Comment: @Anton the sole line `const sr = require('seed-random')` works fine, no error.

Comment: @richarddmorey Can you think of something else that you did/configured? Is there another line of code in your `index.js` file? How are you trying to run your node code? There's something missing here as I have a working version of your setup.

Comment: @anton - actually, just tried adding the line `var a = sr()` and that resulted in the same error
@stvn - no, that is literally the only line in `index.js`. Could it be something with how play.js sets up a project? I’m pretty new at this.

Comment: oh, right. play.js. I'm not familiar with that and read over it in your problem description. Absolutely sure that that has something to do with it.

Comment: I did some research on play.js and apparently it still has limited support for node modules. One of the things I read is to try using a module bundler (like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [ncc](https://github.com/vercel/ncc)) to try and pack everything together and avoid module issues. Maybe you could give that a try.